# ros2 bag record <topic_name> failed to load entry point 'record'

Tags: ros2, bagfile, rosbag-record

I just finished installing ROS2 Humble for Windows and am trying to work through the tutorials in the documentation, but I am stuck on the "recording and playing back data" tutorial in the "Beginner: CLI tools" section.

I set up my workspace and successfully started the '/turtlesim' and '/teleop_turtle' nodes using the following two commands:

```
ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node

ros2 run turtlesim turtle_teleop_key
```

After this I attempted to record the data using the command:

```
ros2 bag record /turtle1/cmd_vel
```

which produces the following error:

```
    Failed to load entry point 'record': DLL load failed while importing _reader: The specified module could not be found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Scripts\ros2-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.18.7', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')())
  File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\ros2cli\cli.py", line 50, in main
    add_subparsers_on_demand(
  File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\ros2cli\command\__init__.py", line 250, in add_subparsers_on_demand
    extension.add_arguments(
  File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\ros2bag\command\bag.py", line 26, in add_arguments
    add_subparsers_on_demand(
  File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\ros2cli\command\__init__.py", line 237, in add_subparsers_on_demand
    extension = command_extensions[name]
KeyError: 'record'
```

Does anyone understand what this error means and what I might be doing wrong/missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot comment to get more details, but I think `rosbag2` may not be installed in your system.

You can check that by running `ros2 pkg prefix rosbag2`; if it says `Package not found` you need to clone the [repo](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2), check out the `humble` branch and build it from sources.

Comment: running `ros2 pkg prefix rosbag2` just prints my ros2 directory, which for me is C:\dev\ros2_humble. I assume this means I do have rosbag2 installed? I did originally install ros2 from binary packages if that helps